# Unity ontriggerenter2d not working sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating a 2D platformer car game like hill climb racing. I have a function where player vehicle collects boosters and fuels on the way to goal. It is done by using OnTriggerEnter2D. It works totally fine while I play the game in the editor and also on the Bluestacks emulator. But I don't have a android phone so I send he vpk to my friends for testing but they always complain that the Booster will collect sometimes but sometimes it will not collect and the vehicles just passes through it. I made Booster a prefab and use it to all the levels but they say that the booster is collected some times but sometimes it is not collected even in the same level. I use same method for fuel and the booster but fuel works fine. What may be causing this problem? My vehicle has a rigidBody and is set to continuous collision detection. And the error can happen at any time in any level.

Collsion Handling code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Nboost"))
    {
        Booster.stat_boost_pick_sound.Play();
        Booster.collectedBoost += 1f;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);

    }

    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("fuel"))
    {
        Booster.stat_boost_pick_sound.Play();
        Speedometer.static_fuel += 20f;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);

    }
}
```

Car movement code:

```
void MoveCar()
{
    static_frontWheel.AddTorque(-input * static_carSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    static_backWheel.AddTorque(-input * static_carSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    static_car.AddTorque(-input * static_carTorque * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: hmm, a couple questions (add the answers to your post): Is your vehicle a rigidBody? What are your physics and game time steps?  Does this bug only happen on later levels or does it happen at pretty much any time?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear what is physics and game time steps?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen for multiple reasons(given the question only explains so little, I’ll write all possible solutions):

• The cars are so ‘fast’ the collider of the car passes through the collider of the booster. Try to change the car’s collision detection to continuous. This can be done at the rigidbody of the car. Alternatively you could increase the collider sizes of cars or boosts

• Some of the boosts in the scene don’t have the correct tag.

• Some of the boosts in the scene are in a layer that doesn’t have its collisions enabled with the car’s layer

Comment: The collision detection is on continuous. And the size may be enough because same size fuel doesn't have this error. Boosts are made from a prefab so every boost has exactly same tag. Boosts are in default layer. I'll try to increase the boost's box collider's size and see what happens. What I find most interesting is it happens only in mobile phones but not in editor and emulator. May be due to some CPU speeds. I don't know.

Comment: @AmmuTammu you can try to fps cap your editor and test if fps is the problem, but setting the collision detection to continuous should effectively remove the fps "problem". Learn how to fps cap editor [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html)